# Advantages of Using Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) Over Other Machine Learning Algorithms for Classification Tasks

Tags: neural-networks, classification, recurrent-neural-network

As far as I know, one of the main advantages of using RNN is to learn sequences of texts from the (textual) data set. If I am correct, this is intuitive to understand when RNN is applied to a task such as text generation (e.g. predicting next words, building Q&A bot, text summarization). I've seen a lot of blog posts and online course materials performing RNN for text classification tasks such as sentiment analysis or news article categorization.

My question: What is the benefit of using RNN for these types of text classification tasks when these also can be done using other ML algorithms such as SVM, Naive Bayes, and etc?

 The reason for raising this question is that I wasn't sure how identifying sequences of texts works or whether this is needed for the classification tasks where sequences seem do not matter.